# Find all user1 owned and user1's group executable files in the directory in Linux

Tags: linux

I want to find all *`user1`* owned and *`user1`*'s group executable files in the directory in Linux.

Using `find` following works fine :

```
find /$mydir -type f -user user1 -perm -010
```

but need to know how can I do the same thing with `ls` and `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command does recursive search if `maxdepth` is not specified.

For the current directory:

`ls -l | awk '$3=="user1"&&$4=="user1group"&&substr($1,1,1)=="-"&&substr($1,7,1)=="x" {print $NF}'` will work when you know user1's group.

Or using recursive search among groups in all subfolders:

```
user="user1";for s in `groups $user| sed 's/.*: //g'`; do awkstmt="ls -R -l | awk '\$3==\"$user\"&&\$4==\""$s"\"&&substr(\$1,1,1)==\"-\"&&substr(\$1,7,1)==\"x\" {print \$NF}'"; eval $awkstmt; done | sort | uniq
```

Or recursive search among groups in current folder:

```
user="user1";for s in `groups $user| sed 's/.*: //g'`; do awkstmt="ls -l | awk '\$3==\"$user\"&&\$4==\""$s"\"&&substr(\$1,1,1)==\"-\"&&substr(\$1,7,1)==\"x\" {print \$NF}'"; eval $awkstmt; done | sort | uniq
```